# variable declaration on php 7 with ? near type

Tags: php

I saw this syntax, and I'm not sur about its meaning of the ? near the variable type

```
 class A {
    public int $a;
    public ?int $b;
    public int $c; 
}
```

It means that $b can be null?

Comment: Yes, that means it is [nullable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it's a relatively new feature from php 7.1 onwards. Prefixing the type with a ? makes it nullable.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php for a (modestly) more detailed explanation and examples.